# ArcGIS Server Object Extensions: how do I deploy extra .dll's?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, c#, c++

I am developing an ArcGIS Server Object Extensions in C# that makes calls into a C++ .dll.
How do I add this .dll to deployment?
By that I mean that I want it included in the .soe.

Comment: I would assume that the build process adds it the .soe file, is that not the case?

Comment: No. I tried to add the .dll as a reference to the Visual Studio C# project but it will not allow this since the .dll is not an assembly or COM component. So VS has no way to know that I want to include the .dll. I am using Pinvoke to call C++ (C actually) from C# so there is no link dependency either (resolved at runtime).

Comment: You're planning to use that as via COM? (e.g not using a wrapper)   Maybe try to register it on the machines using regasm, like it used to be in 10.0? [This video](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1184/extending-arcgis-101-for-server-services) shows how to register the SOE DLL at around minute 41

Comment: Sorry just released you're using PInvoke, only thing I can think of is ILMerge.

Comment: If possible I would like to not use COM. I just mentioned that since it was one of the things I could reference and I was thinking that if I had a reference to the .dll VS would have some way to understand which .dll I want to include.